# EKS Cluster high CPU usage datadog monitor

Tags: amazon-eks, datadog

I would like to create a datadog monitor which alerts if multiple hosts of an EKS cluster has high CPU usage. I'm calculating the CPU usage with the following formula:

sum:kubernetes_state.container.cpu_requested{cluster_name:xxx} by {node} / sum:kubernetes_state.node.cpu_allocatable{cluster_name:xxx} by {node} * 100

[my datadog monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WnzJ.png)

I found an article which shows how to create cluster alerts, but it's not for EKS:
https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/guide/create-cluster-alert/

I can combine these together. Anyone has experence with these monitors?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the system-cpu-idle.
This is the solution.

QUERY --> avg(last_1m):100 - avg:system.cpu.idle{cluster_name:*} by {host,kube_cluster_name} > 85[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1dNF.png)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it